# Query not producing desired results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is the table structure of my table - group_table

[image]

The result I need should be as below

[image]

Below is the query I tried using. But not producing the result as desired.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT A.PARENTID,A.NAME,A.CAPTION,A.PMKID,A.MKTPLANID,A.CATEGORY
FROM GROUP_TABLE A
)P
PIVOT
(
MAX(NAME)
FOR CAPTION IN ([Rollup],[Appeal Category],[PME])
)S
```

Comment: FYI, I'm guessing you're not getting your desired results because you're including PARENTID in your select list (which is going to give you a row for each of your unique IDs rather than just two rows like that). Also, there's not really anything to group by in your select list so what MAX(Name) you're looking for is going to matter.

Answer (score 2):

This might be easier with conditional aggregation:

```
select mktplanid,
       max(case when caption = 'Rollup' then name end) as rollup,
       max(case when caption = 'Appeal Category' then name end) as appealcategory,
       max(case when caption = 'Planned Appeal' then name end) as plannedappeal,
       max(case when caption = 'PME' then name end) as PME,
       max(pmkid) as pmkid
from (select gt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by caption, mktplanid ORDER BY mktplanid) as seqnum 
      from group_table gt
     ) gt
group by mktplanid, seqnum;
```

Comment: Hi, this is producing me an error saying - The function row_number must have an over clause with Order by

Comment: Try now, please :)

Comment: This is not producing me the result as desired. But, there is a small change in the question as I got table data edited. Will edit the question screenshot right away. Please check out.

Comment: Below is my latest trial code. This works partially. In this code, I am not able to bring the MKTplanID   



select a.name as 'Roll up', b.name as 'Appeal Category', C.NAME as 'Planned Appeal', D.NAME as 'PME'
from GROUP_TABLE A 
left outer JOIN GROUP_TABLE B ON A.MKTPLANID = B.MKTPLANID AND A.PARENTID = B.PMKID
left outer JOIN GROUP_TABLE C ON A.MKTPLANID = C.MKTPLANID AND B.PARENTID = C.PMKID
left outer JOIN GROUP_TABLE D ON A.MKTPLANID = D.MKTPLANID AND C.PARENTID = D.PMKID
where a. caption = 'Roll up'